# Tiger to Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I'm running Mac OS X 10.4.11 on a 2007 MacBook. I want to upgrade to Mavericks, but I can't do so without using the Mac App Store to download the upgrade. Tiger doesn't have the Mac App Store. How can I get around this?

Comment: That really doesn't relate to me as I'm working with Apple engineering and should probably just call them.

Answer (score 0):

As you can [see here](http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-10.9-mavericks-faq/os-x-mavericks-compatible-macs-system-requirements.html), your MacBook is too old and is not compatible with Mavericks nor with [Mountain Lion](https://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-mountain-lion-faq/macs-compatible-incompatible-with-os-x-mountain-lion.html).

Comment: According to both that link and Apple's website, my computer is compatible with Mavericks.

Comment: Is it a Macbook Pro or a MacBook ? Because only the Pro 2007 are indeed compatible. (Even if for performance sake I would not update)

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks is a free upgrade only if you already have 10.6 or higher.  If you have 10.4 or 10.5, you need to at least purchase the 10.6 upgrade for $19.99 from the Apple Store.  Installing 10.6 will give you the App Store and the ability to upgrade to Mavericks for free assuming your hardware will run Mavericks.

[Snow Leopard (US Apple Store)](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard)